# Creating a search filter and one of the fields is from other table

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

So I`m trying to create a search filter.

And i have created this:

```
$data = Input::all();
$ads = new Ads();

if($data['description']) {
    $ads = $ads->where('description', 'LIKE', '%' . $data['description'] . '%');
}

if($data['min']) {
    $ads = $ads->where('price', '>', $data['min']);
}

if($data['max']) {
    $ads = $ads->where('price', '<', $data['max']);
}
```

And I have $data['city']. But the problem is that $ads dont have a city, it has userID and every user has its city. How would i do something like this but it would actualy search the user that owns this ad and check if the city is like the searched one.

I tried somthing like this:

```
    $resultAds = $ads;

    if($data['city']) {
        foreach($resultAds as $rAds) {
            if($rAds->compareCity($data['city'])) {
                $resultAds[] = $rAds;
            }
        }
    }

    $resultAds = $resultAds->paginate(12);
```

But that dosnt work.
It gives this error:
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_ERROR) 
Call to a member function compareCity() on a non-object
And $rAds is for somereason boolean? I think thats becouse i havent done the ->get(); but i cannot do that becouse i would like to paginate the results.

Thanks for help.

So now my problem is to create a realationship to get city field out of users table.

### Ads table

```
id
description
price
userID
```

### User table

```
id
username
password
phone
city
```

I need to make a releationship so i could get all the ads with the requested city based on what city has the user with the userID taken from ads table.

Comment: Do you have a city table ?

Comment: No I don`t have a city table. The city field is entered by a user.

Comment: then where is the city information in database ?

Comment: It is a field in the users table.

Comment: from what I understand so far, i don't think its a good idea. You should probably have a city table. If you have a city table, then you can join tables and fetch data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is like this:

```
if($data['city']) {
    $ads = $ads->whereHas('users', function ($q) use($data) {
        $q->where('city','LIKE','%'.$data['city'].'%');
    });
}
```

This is the solution that worked. It is kinda taken from the other answer.

And I needed to add this in the model:

```
public function users() {
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}
```

And now it works.
Thanks everyone for help!

Answer (score 1):

You would want to use whereHas as long as your relationship methods are setup correctly.

```
if($data['city'])
{
    $ads->whereHas('users', function($q) use ($data)
    {
        $q->where('city', $data['city']);
    });
}
```

Comment: Uhm.. I dont think i have set up releationship. Can u help me with that? Or point me to a good tutorial..

Answer (score 1):

If the ad to user is a belongsTo relationship, then you don't need a table or even to setup a relationship just to filter on city field from users table. You can do a join on the users table. I am assuming your user table is called users:

```
if($data['city']) {
    $ads = $ads->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'city.userID')
       ->where('users.city','like','%'.$data['city'].'%');
}
```

The advantage of a join over whereHas is that it has no subquery that is executed against every row of the ads table, making it more efficient. Additionally, if you always join the users table, whether there is a filter on city or not, then you can pull the city from the users into the ads without having to do additional queries or with() relationships. Like this:

```
$ads = $ads->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'city.userID')
if($data['city']) {
    $ads = $ads->where('users.city','like','%'.$data['city'].'%');
}
```

later:

```
$result = $ads->get(['ads.*', (new Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression('users.city')]);
```

or if you are going to paginate the result:

```
$result = $ads->paginate($pageSize, [
    'ads.*', 
    (new Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression('users.city'))
    ]);
```

every `$ad` that is in the `$result` will have a `$ad->city` field.